# Why would Gamora go to Knowhere assuming Thanos would be there?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Thor, after getting rescued from the ship explosion in *Avengers: Infinity War*, informs the Guardians that Thanos is after all the Infinity Stones.

He also states that nobody knows where the Soul Stone is, so he can’t get them all.

Problem is, Gamora knows where the Soul Stone is. And we find out later that she’s told Nebula about it too. At this point Gamora should’ve realized she puts the whole universe in jeopardy by getting anywhere near Thanos.

She does ask Quill to kill her if she gets captured but this is a massive tactical error (IMO).

Answer (score 9):

### Because Gamora wanted to kill Thanos

We see that Thanos gave a knife to Gamora when he wiped half the population of her planet. She used that knife to kill him when she goes to Knowhere. Since it was an illusion created by Thanos, he doesn't die.

She asks Quill to kill him only because she knows the location of the Soul Stone and if she gets captured, Thanos will make her reveal it no matter how.

> **Gamora:** I want you to promise me...
>   you'll kill me.
>
> **Quill:** What?
>
> **Gamora:** I know something he doesn't. And if he finds it out, the entire universe could be at risk.

[Script Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=avengers-infinity-war)